# Sharing a variable between different classes in Tornado

Tags: python, http, tcp, tornado

I am trying to write a Tornado TCP + HTTP Server application.

My use case is a Tornado TCP + HTTP Server application which accepts data from a TCP client and pass the data to display it on a webpage hosted on the HTTP server.

Here is my tornado server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os.path
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.web
import logging
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen
from tornado.iostream import StreamClosedError
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer
from tornado.options import options, define

define("port", default=6642, help="TCP port to listen on")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

test = {}

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        global test 
        self.render('index.html', test=test)

class EchoServer(TCPServer):
    @gen.coroutine
    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        global test 
        while True:
            try:
                test = yield stream.read_until("\n")
                logger.info("Received bytes: %s", test)
            except StreamClosedError:
                logger.warning("Lost client at host %s", address[0])
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application( handlers=[
        (r'/', IndexHandler)], 
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"))
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    server = EchoServer()
    server.listen(6641)
    logger.info("Listening on TCP port %d",6641)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

Here is the python client code :

```
# echo_client.py
import socket
import time
counter = 0

host = '192.168.43.59'    
port = 6641              # The same port as used by the server
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
while True:
    s.sendall("s\n")
    counter = counter + 1
    time.sleep(5)
```

I want to pass the data received from TCP client application into the variable "test" to the render template to display in index.html webpage but I am getting no data displayed.

I am using the global variable concept but no success since couldn't pass the updated "test" variable to index.html page.

If anyone could throw light on using common vaiables across different classes or handlers would help me.

Javascript file iam using is this :

```
/* test.js */
var test = ""

function set_test(val)
{
    test=val
}

function show_test()
{
    alert(test);
}
```

The HTML template used is this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30" />
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="{{ static_url('scripts/test.js') }}" 
type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="show_test()" value="alert" />
    <script type="application/javascript">
        set_test("{{test}}");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi xyres,

Thank you for your spontaneous reply.I went through the link provided by you and after going through it i could understand that q.get() and q.put() can be used to store and retrieve data as you said.But i could not after modifying the tornado server code in the following manner I couldn't receive the data from TCP client , before this i could at least get data from TCP client .Can you let me know what is the mistake i have done in queue implementation

Here is my tornado server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os.path
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.web
import logging
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado import gen
from tornado.iostream import StreamClosedError
from tornado.tcpserver import TCPServer
from tornado.options import options, define

define("port", default=6642, help="TCP port to listen on")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

#test = {}
q = Queue(maxsize=2)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        #global test
        test = yield q.get 
        self.render('index.html', test=test)

class EchoServer(TCPServer):
    @gen.coroutine
    def handle_stream(self, stream, address):
        #global test
        yield q.put(test)
        yield q.join() 
        while True:
            try:
                test = yield stream.read_until("\n")
                logger.info("Received bytes: %s", test)
            except StreamClosedError:
                logger.warning("Lost client at host %s", address[0])
                break
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application( handlers=[
        (r'/', IndexHandler)], 
        static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"))
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    server = EchoServer()
    server.listen(6641)
    logger.info("Listening on TCP port %d",6641)
    IOLoop.current().start()
```

As per the tornado documentation it seems that queue can be applied to coroutines and here iam trying to replicate the same to two different classes.Is that a mistake ..Iam new to tornado so please bear my silly questions ..

Comment: Use Tornado queues: https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html. Put the received data into a queue and retrieve it in your request handler and then render the template.

Comment: As per the tornado documentation it seems that queue can be applied to coroutines and here iam trying to replicate the same to two different classes.Is that a mistake ..Iam new to tornado so please bear my silly questions ..

Comment: You can make your `get` handler a coroutine. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: Hi xyres,I am using python 2.7.13

Answer (score 0):

You've a multiple options:

1. If you want to have a long-running connection, for example, if a client sends a request to `IndexHandler` and you want the client to wait until a message is in the queue, you can convert your handler to a coroutine.
2. If you want to return the response immediately, regardless of the availability of the data in the queue, you can use a queue's `get_nowait()` method.

Example for case #1:

```
from tornado.queues import Queue

q = Queue()


class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.data_future = q.get()

        data = yield self.data_future

        self.render('index.html', data=data)

    def on_connection_close(self):
        # set an empty result on the future
        # if connection is closed so that 
        # the messages don't get removed from
        # the queue unnecessariliy for 
        # closed connections
        self.msg_future.set_result(None)
```

Example for case #2:

```
from tornado.queues import Queue, QueueEmpty

q = Queue()

def get(self):
    try:
        data = q.get_nowait()
    except QueueEmpty:
        data = None
    self.render(...)
```